# Why does Voldemort hold his wand in this manner?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

Is there any reason for the unusual way in which Lord Voldemort holds his wand?

[image: A picture depicting Voldemort barely holding his wand in his right hand. Instead of gripping it like most other wizards would, it seems like the wand is merely resting in his hand, in a floating fashion, between his thumb, his index finger and his middle finger.]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was a film decision, made by the character acter Ralph Fiennes, in conjunction with Production Designer Stuart Craig. In short, Fiennes was trying to make Voldemort's action tally with the book description of him as snake-like, with "*silky-smooth*" movements. The wand, he felt, should be an extension of these movements.

> *"She* [JKR] *describes the voice in a couple of places at least, which was a good indicator of where to go and the snake-like idea that J.K. Rowling gives him as someone, but that he himself has snake-like elements to his movement, silky-smooth and silent"*
>
> *"With Stuart Craig, who's the production designer, and his team, we
> discussed what the wand would be, It has a hook
> on it, so I can hold my hand, and then the end can hook around this
> finger. **I remember it should feel like an extension of my hand ... Like I almost have the hand open** ... you'd think it would fall off the hand. But I just enjoyed that it could be light in the hand."*

and

> *When we, when I was first discussing the part, I talked to the design department about creating a little hook, or a bird's claw on the end* [of the wand] *so that it could rest in an open hand, which I quite liked.*